# Color code cells in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

I need to color code two GridViews. The color coding should expose data discrepancies between the two GridViews. The data is stored in DataTables. Since the DataTable may be used for different controls, I’d prefer to flag the data discrepancy within the DataTable.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to actually be a question -- what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @patmortech I think he wants to know how he can do it... that's how I took it anyway.

Comment: @BrianMains Sure, but for the sake of future visitors and for clarity, it'd be better if a) his title reflected more about what is going to actually be answered (adding a flag column to a DataTable), and b) he is more specific about his code and what part of the process he is unable to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to use the DataTable for flagging, you would have to add an extra column to store the flag, so you could retrieve it in the RowDataBound event of the GridView to change the color.  That is certainly possible; however, if for some reason that doesn't work, you could create a wrapper class for each row, that represents the row and has the additional data you need.  That makes it more complex to bind, but it would work.